# Web API for get teacher directory

Tags: asp.net, json, http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am going to develop a rest service using Web API. For that we have a requirement that we have a number of parents who can able to login to the application as a parent. There is an access token provided for each user who accessing the application after successful login.

There is a service available for each parent to get the list of teachers who are teaching their child. There may be more than one child for a parent. The list of childid available at the client when parent get logged in.

1. So we need to pass childid with accesstoken of the user to the api. Which is the best method to pass. Is it a GET or POST including childid as json body?
2. What is the best method for creating service like this. GET or POST? including accesstoken in HEADER or any other way. like inside json?

Answer (score -1):

One way of implementing this might be to give each user (parent) [Claims](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee517291.aspx) representing their parentage of each child. These would then be added to the user's principal [in the manner described in this article](http://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-identity-stripped-bare-mvc-part-2). Some data store (for example, a database table) would record which users (parents) are parents of which children. Finally, in the API action method, compare the id of the child whose information is requested to the list of child claims on the user's principal, and if the id isn't present, return a 4xx status code (probably a `403 Forbidden`).

Something like:

```
// Cast the Thread.CurrentPrincipal
IClaimsPrincipal icp = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as IClaimsPrincipal;

// Access IClaimsIdentity which contains claims
IClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = (IClaimsIdentity)icp.Identity;

// Access claims
if(claimsIdentity.Claims
   .Where(c => c.ClaimType == "name-of-your-custom-claim")
   .Select(c => c.Resource.ToString())
   .Contains(childId)) { return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
```

Should work. Haven't tested the code or checked that it compiles; it's an example to give the gist. I may clean it up later.